# Как вернутьтаблицу в исходное состояние после сортировки?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet

Смоделирую ситуацию. Допустим есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включаем фильтр по названию айтема (скрываем всё кроме "А"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее сортируем колонка G "ФИО" (А - Я):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снимаем фильтр название айтема (выбираем "показать всё"):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате, строки с айтемом "А" остались отсортированными по имени!
**Как же вернуть таблицу в исходное положение (без фильтров и сортировок)???**

P.S. откат (Ctrl+Z) не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вернуть в исходное состояние, нужно это состояние как-то помнить. Без какого-либо указателя (критерия, флага, номера, etc.), по которому можно определить начальное состояние таблицы, ничего не получится.

"Памятью" может служить столбец с номером строки.

В первом столбце, где нумерация, перед действиями с сортировкой/фильтрацией формулу заменить на значения. Если формула по каким-либо соображениям должна остаться (например, порядковый номер отфильтрованных строк), то нумерацию проставить в отдельном столбце.

Сортировать по этому столбцу по возрастанию, предварительно раскрыв все фильтры.

Если вообще "*без фильтров и сортировок*", как указано в вопросе, то только писать скрипт (для *Excel* - на *VBA*, для *Google*-таблицы - на *JavaScript*). Но макрос не всесильный и ему тоже нужно рассказать, как строки расставить.

' -----------------------------

Чтобы формула нумерации видимых строк не ломалась и правильно работала, столбец с формулой нужно "оторвать" - не включать столбец в фильтр. Для гарантии формулу можно отделить о таблицы с фильтром пустым столбцом.

Формула, считающая значения в видимых ячейках:

```
=ПРОМЕЖУТОЧНЫЕ.ИТОГИ(3;$C$2:C2)
=SUBTOTAL(3;$C$2:C2)
```

Comment: Ответ понятен. Спасибо!